# How to avoid postgres messing up with the ids of entity

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

I found a problem today on my postgres database , I have an entity with primary key , what I store in there are ids like 1, 2, 3, 4 , etc.

I checked the database again today and found that all the Ids were all mess up, like 4, 2, 1 etc. They were not in the order as they were stored.

The only thing I've done with such table is saving new data and doing queries about the entity. My question is, what might have caused the database to mess up like that?

How could I avoid that from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have fundamentally misunderstood how the database works. There *is no order* in a table. The database sorts rows when you tell it to using `ORDER BY`. Otherwise it can spit them out in any order it likes based on whatever method of fetching them is fastest.

The physical row order can be changed by `UPDATE` replacing row versions, by `VACUUM` etc.